# Why is there an extra bottom margin?

Tags: css, layout, screen, padding, margin

My black border triangle is centered. But there is an extra bottom margin and (hence the scroll bar appears). Why?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.canvas {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh 5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="canvas">
    Dummy text
  </div>

</body>
```

[a screenshot of the black border triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqJba.png)

Comment: i think it's because you set an height of 90vh

Comment: @Sfili_81 it's because the top margin is collapsing with the body margin

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the `margin: 5vh 5%;`. To center a div I would suggest to use flex:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;

  /* Center div */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.canvas {
  border: 10px solid black;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="canvas">
    Dummy text
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just curious. So before css flex came around, there was no way to avoid that bottom margin and scroll bar?

Comment: There [are a couple more ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/14246637) to do it but I prefer flexbox